# For loop within then() does not iterate

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to build html and insert results to it from db. submitData returns a promise, and if check works when console logged, but when it reaches for loop it just stops, no errors. I can't seem to figure out.

```js
submitData(submit, ('GET'), (api + '/' + id))
            .then((pc) => {
                if (pc.length !== 0) {
                    //console log here gives results
                    for (let j = 0; j < pc.length; j++) {
                        //console log here no results, no errors
                        cBuilder(
                            sPost, 
                            (pc[j].user),
                            (pc[j].username),
                            (pc[j].time),
                            (pc[j].text)
                        )
                    }
                }
            });
```

Console log after if statment:

```
Object { pc:(4) [...]}
```

cBuilder is building html, and placing values from argument list in the correct place. For loop is not called for some reason. Console log right after if statment gives result, when console log first line after for gives noting, does not iterate so cBuilder is not even called at all.

```js
cBuilder(sPost, ...){
let scd = document.createElement('div');
    scd.setAttribute('class', 'col-md-12');
    sPost.appendChild(scd);
.
.
.
```

Comment: What does `pc` contain right before your for-loop?

Comment: @Gavin it has object, if console logged

Comment: object doesn't have a length

Comment: Print `pc.length` before your for loop.

Comment: I think pc doesn't contain length property.

Comment: Instead of letting people guess about your `pc` variable why don't you just post it in the question since obviously it is important data regarding the question?

Comment: [Off-topic] The `if(pc.length !== 0){` statement is unnecessary, your `for` loop won't run if `pc.length` is `0`...

Comment: And your If condition is passing because you are checking pc.length !== 0 and if pc doesn't contain length property then pc.length will be undefined not 0

Comment: It would be `pc.pc.length`

Comment: @epascarello actually that is correct

Comment: @Djisin you should provide us your console.log before the loop or try `console.log (pc.length)` and see by yourself whether `pc` has a a `length` or not.

Comment: @MoisésFerreira console log pc.lenght is undefined..

Comment: Exactly, it's because the value of your callback is a dict, not a set (array). The answer below is good, because he gets the callback (dict) and take the array `pc` from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log statement shows this: `Object { pc:(4) [...]}` which means your code is returning an object back with a property that has an array it in. In your code you are trying to loop over the object not the array.

```
...
.then((result) => {
  var pc = result.pc
  if (pc && pc.length !== 0) { }
})
```

Comment: Help is appreciated! Thank you.